# Clean character observation from duplicate factor levels

Tags: r, concatenation, levels

The situation is the following: I have a column "a" that is of class *character*, containing many integers. Each integer represents a category. I would like to know for each observation what unique levels they include. 
Column b represents the desired result: cleaned for duplicates, yet representing each unique level.
What I would like to know is how I could clean column a, so that it looks like column b. I need to implement the solution to 60k rows.

```
                                                       a          b
1 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5 |   4, 5
2                            2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 |   2
3           86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 8, 8 |   86, 37, 8   

a <- c("4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5, 4, 5", "2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2", "86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 8, 8")
b <- c("4, 5", "2", "86, 37, 8")
df <- data.frame(a, b)
```

I have read a few posts about dropping duplicate factor values, but as you can try out yourself this does not yield anything useful.

```
droplevels(factor(df$a))
```

This basically solves the issue, but it is not feasible for 60k rows.

```
df$a[1] <- factor(unique(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(df$a[1], "[[:digit:]]+")))))
df$a[2] <- factor(unique(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(df$a[2], "[[:digit:]]+")))))
df$a[3] <- factor(unique(as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(df$a[3], "[[:digit:]]+")))))
```

Comment: It's worth asking yourself the question, is my data in the right format? If you have strings full of comma-separated numbers, then maybe you really want to create a list of vectors, or a grouped data frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the use of `sapply` here. That prevents you from having to construct element by element, eg like this:

```
df$a <- sapply(a,function(i){
  paste(unique(strsplit(i,", ")[[1]]),
        collapse = ", ")
})

df$a
#> [1] "4, 5"      "2"         "86, 37, 8"
```

Keep in mind that `strsplit()` works on character vectors. So either use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when constructing the data, or convert the factor variables first to character using `as.character()`. In my code I just use the vector `a`.

On a sidenote: I love the `stringr` package, but in this case `strsplit()` will give you faster code. Using the code above, you avoid a lot of overhead created by the regular expressions you use.